# Search for whole word in text in Matlab

Tags: string, matlab, char

I try to look for a specific combination of characters. The combination is the following : "text":

The quotation marks and the colon are part of it. I tried it with the ismember() function of Matlab, however, it is always checking for each of the characters on its own, I am not able to search for the whole string. Below is an reproducible example.

```
ismember('"text":', '"text": asdf')
% What it returns:    1   1   1   1   1   1   1
% What I want it to return: 1

ismember('"text":', '"teasdfxt": asdf')
% What it returns:    1   1   1   1   1   1   1
% What I want it to return: 0

% I also tried the following options, both did not work
ismember(""text":", '"teasdfxt": asdf')
cellfun(@length, strfind('"text": asdf', '"text":'))
```

Comment: If you have MATLAB 2016b or later, maybe [`contains`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/contains.html)?

Comment: How about `~isempty(strfind('"text": asdf', '"text":'))`?

Comment: Using the code of @saastn I get the recommendation by MATLAB to replace it with the following code: `contains('"text": asdf', '"text":')`. This works fine and answers my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using Contains and Writing Quotation Marks in Strings

Using contains as the comment above suggests is a great way to check if a substring exists within another string. Also if you wish your string to have single quotes `'` or double quotes `"` they can be written by typing them twice `""` and `''`. After doing this it is best to open on the variable in the workspace window to view if the strings come out as expected.

```
%Checking if string exists%
String_Of_Interest = """text"":";
String_To_Search = """text"": asdf";

contains(String_To_Search,String_Of_Interest)
```

An important thing to note when dealing with strings in MATLAB is

### String vs Character Arrays

'Text' → Returns a character array of dimension 1 by 4.

"Text" → Returns a string.

```
String = "text";
Character_Array = 'text';
```

[image: Character Array vs String]

**Using MATLAB version: R2019b**

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Unfortunately, my string of interest is `"text":` and not `"text"`. I have to be able to also search for the `:`. The comment of saastn worked for me.

Comment: @00koeffers My bad missed the colon. I just edited the answer to include it now.